# Border inset on background fill - CSS

Tags: css

Hi need a css for the following mock up

[image: Border inset]

how to make border leaving 10 px on both ends on bottom,with a background fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to look right, you'll need nested `div`:

```
.inner {
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #666;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    width: 200px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.outer {
    width: 200px; 
    border: 10px solid #666; /* your grey fill */
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ugodi)

Just mess with `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on the `.inner` element to get the spacing you want.

Comment: the border should appear inside the grey box how to achieve that

Comment: You only need `.outer { background-color: #666;} .inner { margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid #000;}`